# Asynk Task With PhoneGap in Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-asynctask

Here I want to call html pages.I have use Phone Gap for that. But right now I want to call html pages with AsyncTask.So can someone help me how to call
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/chapter_one.html", 10000); in AsyncTask.

Here is my Activity Code.

```
public class Chapter_Detail extends DroidGap
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          Intent intent = getIntent();
          String stringContent = intent.getExtras().getString("Chapter_Content");
          Log.e("stringContent in Performance Details  "," = " + stringContent);

          if(stringContent.equals("oop concept"))
          {
              super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/chapter_one.html", 10000);
          }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it with help of ajax call.Below code calls a service url and u will get the response.

```
function callRest(uName, pwd, serviceUrl, pxml) 
            {
          $.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: serviceUrl,
                dataType: "text",
                username: uName,
                password: pwd,
                statusCode: {
                    200: function () {

                    },
                    500: function () {

                    }
                },

                success: function (res, status, xhr) {
                //res contains response,
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, status, error_is) {
                    alert('Error: ' + error_is);
                }
            });
        }
```